# How to configure Zuul gateway(which is listening on two ports) to decline requests based on port and url combination?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, netflix-zuul

I have a use case where my Zuul gateway needs to be accessed from another Spring Boot app and from the browser.
Spring Boot app needs to authenticate itself to Zuul with certificate. So i enabled two way ssl on port 8762, and i enabled one way ssl on port 8763 for browser access. But the problem is that now i can access every endpoint through 8763 port. Is there a way to force access to certain urls just through 8762? Per example urls which contain "api" can be accessed only through port 8762 and not through port 8763. Is there a way to make such filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom pre-routing [ZuulFilter](http://netflix.github.io/zuul/javadoc/zuul-core/com/netflix/zuul/ZuulFilter.html) that identifies the incoming request and decide if a request needs to be further routed or not.

Get detailed information about the incoming request ([HttpServletRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)) from the context. Here's a sample snippet for your reference:

```
@Override
public String filterType() {
    return FilterConstants.PRE_TYPE;
}

@Override
public int filterOrder() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object run() {
    final RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    final HttpServletRequest request = requestContext.getRequest();

    request.getRemotePort(); // Assign these to a variable to perform your business logic.
    request.getRequestURI();
```